# Replace pattern within string with space

Tags: javascript

I am getting long string with multiple occurances of pattern './.'. The string has dates as well in a format of dd.mm.yyyy.

First I tried with `javascript replace` method as:

`str.replace('./.', '')`. But it replaced only first occurance of './.'

Then I tried another regex which replaces special characters but it didn't work as it replaced '.' within dates as well.

**How do I replace multiple occurances of a pattern './.' without affecting any other characters of a string ?**

Answer (score 0):

1. Escape `.` and d `\`
2. Add a g for global

Like this

```
str = str.replace(/\./\./g, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

`.` is a special character in a regexp, it matches any character, you have to escape it.

```
str.replace(/\.\/\./g, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple pattern:

```
/\.\/\./g
```

to find all "./." strings in your text.

Answer (score 0):

Try it :

```
str.replace(/\.\/\./g, '');
```